docker-mail wont send email due to Error: queue file write error
I am using the docker-mail compose setup.
https://github.com/docker-mailserver/docker-mailserver
I get the following error reported to the client " Error: queue file write error. " when trying to send through SMTP port 587 with STARTSSL, the log seems to be ok after configuring DKIM and DMARC, the log in the server says the following:
mailserver_arti  | 2024-07-25T10:16:10.192362+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1041]: connect from unknown[172.24.0.1]
mailserver_arti  | 2024-07-25T10:16:10.233814+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1041]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[172.24.0.1]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits) key-exchange X25519 server-signature ECDSA (prime256v1) server-digest SHA256
mailserver_arti  | 2024-07-25T10:16:10.267889+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1041]: 3FF4539F00000003F745: client=unknown[172.24.0.1], sasl_method=PLAIN, sasl_username=info@mydomain.com
mailserver_arti  | 2024-07-25T10:16:10.268221+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1153]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[172.24.0.1]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
mailserver_arti  | 2024-07-25T10:16:10.278617+00:00 mail postfix/sender-cleanup/cleanup[1556]: 3FF4539F00000003F745: message-id=<50cc35b1-0778-4e3b-a985-7f5752575092@mydomain.com>
mailserver_arti  | 2024-07-25T10:16:10.278666+00:00 mail postfix/sender-cleanup/cleanup[1556]: 3FF4539F00000003F745: replace: header MIME-Version: 1.0 from unknown[172.24.0.1]; from=<info@mydomain.com> to=<prueba@prueba.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.1.33]>: MIME-Version: 1.0
mailserver_arti  | 2024-07-25T10:16:10.319059+00:00 mail opendkim[625]: 3FF4539F00000003F745: DKIM-Signature field added (s=mail, d=mydomain.com)
mailserver_arti  | 2024-07-25T10:16:10.392078+00:00 mail postfix/sender-cleanup/cleanup[1556]: 5E677F0000000631DB: message-id=<20240725101610.5E677F0000000631DB@mail.mydomain.com>
mailserver_arti  | 2024-07-25T10:16:10.397759+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1041]: disconnect from unknown[172.24.0.1] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=0/1 commands=6/7

I was able to further debug postfix, it seems to be a 451, but it happens even with emails in my own server:
2024-07-25 13:27:53 2024-07-25T11:27:53.856375+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1513]: vstream_fflush_some: fd 22 flush 703
2024-07-25 13:27:53 2024-07-25T11:27:53.856471+00:00 mail postfix/sender-cleanup/cleanup[1719]: CAFCF3C000000001C415: message-id=<36b3e08c-7039-4dee-8e81-1bef6aa63299@mydomain.com>
2024-07-25 13:27:53 2024-07-25T11:27:53.856521+00:00 mail postfix/sender-cleanup/cleanup[1719]: CAFCF3C000000001C415: replace: header MIME-Version: 1.0 from unknown[172.24.0.1]; from=<info@mydomain.com> to=<raul.lapeira@mydomain.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.1.33]>: MIME-Version: 1.0
2024-07-25 13:27:53 2024-07-25T11:27:53.910973+00:00 mail opendkim[143]: CAFCF3C000000001C415: DKIM-Signature field added (s=mail, d=mydomain.com)
2024-07-25 13:27:54 2024-07-25T11:27:53.966245+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1513]: vstream_buf_get_ready: fd 22 got 18
2024-07-25 13:27:54 2024-07-25T11:27:53.966350+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1513]: public/sender-cleanup socket: wanted attribute: status
2024-07-25 13:27:54 2024-07-25T11:27:53.966365+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1513]: input attribute name: status
2024-07-25 13:27:54 2024-07-25T11:27:53.966378+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1513]: input attribute value: 2
2024-07-25 13:27:54 2024-07-25T11:27:53.966399+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1513]: public/sender-cleanup socket: wanted attribute: reason
2024-07-25 13:27:54 2024-07-25T11:27:53.966411+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1513]: input attribute name: reason
2024-07-25 13:27:54 2024-07-25T11:27:53.966427+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1513]: input attribute value: (end)
2024-07-25 13:27:54 2024-07-25T11:27:53.966440+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1513]: public/sender-cleanup socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
2024-07-25 13:27:54 2024-07-25T11:27:53.966453+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1513]: input attribute name: (end)
2024-07-25 13:27:54 2024-07-25T11:27:53.966507+00:00 mail postfix/submission/smtpd[1513]: > unknown[172.24.0.1]: 451 4.3.0 Error: queue file write error

Thanks in advance.

Did you run out of disk space? Check df -h and make sure, particularly where you have mounted the /var/mail and /var/mail-state volumes.

No, the Windows server is ok, already checked disk space because that was my first fear. Docker uses the instance write layer and usually it needs no further config AFAIK

My understanding is that even if I did not mount those folders Docker would just write within the container... isnt it @RyanNoblett? (I mean, it would not survive a recreation but the emails would be sent without any problem)

It can, but there's a limit to how much space is available to the container for ephemeral data, if I recall correctly about 10GB. You really do need to mount these to proper, persistent volumes, in order to not lose any mail should the container be removed.
